# Orthogonal Set of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to find values for a and b for the following set of vectors:

$$\left(\left[\begin{matrix} 1\\2\\3\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix} 4\\1\\-2\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix} a\\b\\3\end{matrix}\right]\right) = 0$$

I know the idea is that, if I take the dot product of all the column vectors in the above vector space, I should end up with zero. But I am not sure how to get started solving for a and b, such that the below set of vectors is orthogonal. A hint as to how to get started?

Comment: The dot product is an operation that is applied to *two* vectors, not three. You mean, *every pairwise dot product* equal to $0$?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I should have said take the dot product of all pairs of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for $(1,2,3)^t$ to be orthogonal to $(a,b,3)^t$, we must have
$$a + 2b + 9 = 0.$$
In order for $(4,1,-2)^t$ to be orthogonal to $(a,b,3)^t$, we must have
$$4a + b - 6 = 0.$$
$(1,2,3)^t$ and $(4,1,-2)^t$ are orthogonal, regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$.

So what you need to do is solve the $2\times 2$ system of linear equations
$$\begin{array}{rccccl}
a & + & 2b & = & -9\\
4a & + & b & = & 6.
\end{array}$$

Do you know how to solve systems of linear equations? (Gaussian-Jordan elimination, for instance?)

Comment: Yes, I know how to solve with Gauss-Jordan. I think I can figure it out now. Thanks.

Comment: Solving the above system I found the following: $\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&3\\0&1&-6\end{matrix}\right]$ . I made sure to check each pairewise dot product, where $a=3$ and $b=-6$, and it does check out. Thanks for the tip.